# In GIMP, how to get a selection from a mask?

Tags: gimp, mask, selections

Let's say I paint a mask in GIMP and I want to convert that to a selection for applying filters, etc. What are the steps for doing this?

Using this sample image from [Pixabay](https://pixabay.com/en/oleander-flower-flowers-pink-187166/) we'll create a mask for the purpose of adding more blur to the background.

Here's the original image:

[image: Original image - pink flowers in the foreground and cityscape in the background]

Next I paint some white around the flowers on a new layer:

[image: White painted around the flowers on a new layer]

Then I add a layer below this one of solid black and merge the layers into a mask:

[image: Black and white mask]

**What is the next step for getting a selection from this mask layer** so that I can apply a filter to only this area? Thanks.

[Note: This is a workflow I use regularly in Photoshop, but still have no idea how to do it in GIMP and would like to know how.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the mask layer is visible, open the Channels list, right click on any of the RGB layers and click *Channel To Selection*.

But instead of painting a layer to get the selection from it, you can directly paint the selection using the [quick mask](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-image-window-qmask-button.html).